# Port missing from URL on Bonobo Git Server

Tags: git, bonobo

Bonobo does not respect my port settings in the "General URL"

e.g **In Browser:**

[image: Browser URL]

**In Bonobo:**
[image: Repo URL]

Can this be made to include the port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should display the right port (as mentioned in [issue 53](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/issues/53)).
One example where it does not can be found in [issue 294](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/issues/294):

> > The server uses the standard port, but when accessing the server from an external URL my router is expecting a different port.
> >     As such, the site displays that the URL is `http://myserverurl.com/MyRepository.git` rather than `http://myserverurl.com:####/MyRepository.git`.
>
> As I mentioned, this is probably because the port your server is listening on (seemingly 80 in your example) does not match your router (`####` in your example).
>
> Bonobo picks up the port from the server it's running on. In order to get them to match, you need to bind the Bonobo server/site to the same port and adjust the NAT on your router to route to the server also on the same port.

Comment: That was it thanks. i made the incorrect assumption that the port would be detected from HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port